# Route isn't calling when it's defined in a separated file

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm trying to structure my node app according to some best practices mentioned [here](https://github.com/i0natan/nodebestpractices/blob/master/sections/projectstructre/breakintcomponents.md) .

But I'm having problems when calling the specific routes.

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const normalizePort = require("./utils/normalize-port");

const app = express();
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.set("port", port);

require("./components/users");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require("./config/database");

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Application started on port : ${port}`));
```

And this is my *index.js* file in `/components/users/`

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const user = require("./users")(router);

module.exports = { user };
```

And this is my *users.js* file which is in the same directory as above *index.js* .

```
module.exports = router => {
  console.log("Hello at First");
  router.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
    console.log("hello");
    res.send("hello");
  });
};
```

Now when I start server in `http://localhost:5000` the console logs the message like this

```
Hello at First
Application started on port : 5000
```

So, it means the file is calling, right ? But when I tried to connect to `http://localhost:5000/hello` which I've defined in `users.js` it gives the error of `Cannot GET /hello` . As I'm gonna define multiple routes in */components/users* folder only I created `index.js` file to export all from a single file. How can I fix this by keeping the same structure ?

Why is that ? Why my route isn't calling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `/components/users/index.js` must export router object instead of another component like

```
const router = require("express").Router();

require("./users")(router);
//require("./others")(router);

module.exports = router;
```

and then use as middleware in your main file

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const normalizePort = require("./utils/normalize-port");

const app = express();
const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.set("port", port);

const usersComponent = require("./components/users");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(usersComponent);
//or point point specific route app.use('/user', usersComponent);

require("./config/database");

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Application started on port : ${port}`));
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. This works the way I expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`/components/users/indexjs` does not do anything, but export `user` which is a function that you defined in `users.js`.

You define and use a `router` object, but you fail to mount/`app.use()` it to the main Express `app`. So a request to `GET /hello` does not exist.

You need to export the `router` object you defined and then:

`app.use('/some-endpoint', routerObject)`

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my issue. Fixed by removind `users.js` and added the route to `/components/users/index.js` , However how can I export multiple routes in a same object ? When I tried that it gives me an error in `server.js` saying that `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`